# Correct procedure for mounting xfs filesystem to use quotas

Tags: debian-wheezy, xfs

I am using a Hetzner box on which I have configured my partitions to use LVM, and have set /home as a xfs filesystem. I use Webmin to administer the box which is running Debian 7.6, and have the following problem when trying to use quotas on there :

Webmin says that quotas can only be enabled at mount.

Sigh. I have googled for days now but the documentation found cannot explain to a dummy like myself what the correct steps would be to implement this correctly, e.g.

1. What/Where/How do I specify the right mount options ?
2. Where / What do I specify to have quotas working then ?

Please feel free to request ANY info you may need I really am totally stuck here ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article over at IBM, which covers quotas on XFS:

https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-lpic1-104-4/

Comment: YESSS thanks very very much THIS is what I was looking for and could not find, problem is resolved, quotas are working, all sooo simple. Webmin still reports that it can only enable at mount but I guess thats a webmin problem, it is working anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The XFS mount option for enabling quotas is 'uquota'..... This can be specified in the appropriate field in a fstab entry, OR as one of the options if you are issuing the mount command manually as root.

Comment: yep I was trying to use 'usrquota' and it just wouldn't go lol, the article marc posted me gave ALL the right answers though, thanks very much.